# Can't send to Kafka from NiFi

Tags: docker, apache-kafka, docker-compose, apache-nifi, kafka-producer-api

I'm running in Docker for Windows and here's my NiFi setup:

[image]

Details on the PublishKafka processor:
[image]

Details on the ConsumeKafka processor:
[image]

Here is my docker-compose file (note: 192.168.1.50 is my static internal host IP):

```html
version: '3'
services:
  Jenkins:
    container_name: Jenkins
    restart: on-failure
    depends_on:
    - NiFi
    image: jenkins:latest
    ports:
      - "32779:50000"
      - "32780:8080"
  NiFi:
    container_name: NiFi
    image: xemuliam/nifi:latest
    restart: on-failure
    depends_on:
    - kafka
    ports:
      - "32784:8089"
      - "32783:8080"
      - "32782:8081"
      - "32781:8443"
    labels:
      com.foo: myLabel
  zookeeper:
    container_name: Zookeeper
    image: wurstmeister/zookeeper
    restart: on-failure
    #network_mode: host
    ports:
      - "2181:2181"
  kafka:
    #container_name: Kafka
    image: wurstmeister/kafka
    depends_on:
    - zookeeper
    #restart: on-failure
    #network_mode: host
    ports:
      - "9092"
    environment:
      #KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://192.168.1.50:9092
      #KAFKA_AUTO_CREATE_TOPICS_ENABLE: "true"
      
      KAFKA_CREATE_TOPICS: "MainIngestionTopic:1:1"
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: 192.168.1.50:2181
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: INSIDE://:9092,OUTSIDE://192.168.1.50:9094
      KAFKA_LISTENERS: INSIDE://:9092,OUTSIDE://:9094
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: INSIDE:PLAINTEXT,OUTSIDE:PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME: INSIDE
      
    volumes:
      - ./var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
```

When I tail the Kafka container log I can see that my topic was created successfully from docker-compose.

Messages are successfully delivered to the PublishKafka processor in NiFi, but then fail to publish.  The ConsumeKafka processor, which is subscribed to the same topic, never receives the message.

The NiFi container log shows the following:

```html
2018-05-28 19:46:18,792 ERROR [Timer-Driven Process Thread-1] o.a.n.p.kafka.pubsub.PublishKafka PublishKafka[id=b2503f49-acc9-38f5-86f9-5029e2768b68] Failed to send all message for StandardFlowFileRecord[uuid=b3f6f818-34d3-42a9-9d6e-636cf17eb138,claim=StandardContentClaim [resourceClaim=StandardResourceClaim[id=1527533792820-1, container=default, section=1], offset=5, length=5],offset=0,name=8151630985100,size=5] to Kafka; routing to failure due to org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Failed to update metadata after 5000 ms.: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Failed to update metadata after 5000 ms.


org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Failed to update metadata after 5000 ms.


2018-05-28 19:46:18,792 INFO [Timer-Driven Process Thread-1] o.a.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer Closing the Kafka producer with timeoutMillis = 5000 ms.
```

I tried publishing to the topic from inside the Kafka container itself but that also failed:

[image]

I have combed documentation and read many threads trying to resolve this issue but it's still an issue.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Hi. I'm not sure why the consumer fails to read but you need to connect `ConsumeKafka` to a downstream processor to actually receive the message. if you have ConsumeKafka's `success` relationship set to auto terminate, you will not get the messsages.

Comment: Hi. Did you try to use your IP `192.168.1.50` instead of `localhost`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use localhost in the "Kafka Brokers" property in NiFi unless the broker was actually running on the same host where NiFi was running. Since you have each service inside a docker container the container for kafka must have a specific hostname or ip that can be used.

Comment: That makes complete sense.  I updated the Kafka Brokers setting in the PublishKafka to look at the kafka machine instead of localhost.  That got me past the metadata update error but now I'm getting "org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Batch Expired"